# Can't create a project from an archetype-catalog.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, archetypes, xmlcatalog

I'm trying to use my own project template, but when I perform the command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

I got the following message:

```
 [INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.
archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
Choose archetype:
   Your filter doesn't match any archetype (hint: enter to return to initial list)
Choose a number or apply filter (format: [groupId:]artifactId, case-sensitive contains): :
```

I tried many possible solutions that I found here, but I did not succeed ...

My steps: 
 - I created a project in eclipse 
 -Then I went to root directory of this project and performed the following command in prompt:

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project
```

and had BUILD SUCCESS.

---

Then I performed the following command on project's folder

```
mvn install
```

and had BUILD SUCCESS

---

I checked the **.m2** folder, and the archetpe-catalog.xml was there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-catalog xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-catalog-1.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-catalog/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <archetypes>
    <archetype>
      <groupId>io.openbdt</groupId>
      <artifactId>framework-openbdt</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <description>framework-openbdt</description>
    </archetype>
  </archetypes>
</archetype-catalog>
```

In maven's documentation explains that default path of **archetypeCatalog=local** is  **path/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml** but on debug (mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local -X), maven search the xml file in **path/.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml**

Note: These steps were typically performed in my notebook, but on my desktop I was unsuccessful. Then I created a new user on the notebook and it also didn't work anymore.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Sometimes maven doesnt work correctly on Eclipse, u should build maven before build your project

Comment: there are a command but i did not remember, ctr alt f5 or something like that, else try mvn build

Answer (score 3):

Maven 3.5.2 is inconsistent location between read and write.

When set [`localRepository`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Settings_Details) in `settings.xml`, `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local` command reads `${localRepository}/archetype-catalog.xml` .

When without `localRepository` setting, that command reads `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml` .

---

`mvn archetype:update-local-catalog` command creates `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml` with `maven-archetype-plugin` **v2.4**.

That command creates `${localRepository}/archetype-catalog.xml` with **v3.0.1** .

---

refs:
[[ARCHETYPE-529] Maven archetype:generate does not find local archetypes in interactive mode - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-529)

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem and reproduced it with Maven versions 3.3.9 and 3.5.2. Probably something is inconsistent in how `mvn install` and `mvn archetype:generate` handle processing `archetype-catalog.xml`.

Because nothing helped for me as well, I created a soft-link:

```
ln -s PATH/TO/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml PATH/TO/.m2/repository/archetype-catalog.xml
```

This made the trick for me. Unfortunately, this works only for unix-like systems.